# NDIS LWF driver causing issues for WFP drivers in the network stack?

Tags: windows-kernel, ndis, kmdf, wfp

I have written a NDIS LWF driver, that gathers send/recv packets, and sends them to the user service, and the user service marks those that are OK, and then we indicate/send those packets that were marked as OK. Note that we first use NdisFSendNetBufferListComplete (in case of send) and NdisFIndicateREceiveNetBufferLists (in case of receive) in our LWF callbacks, and then we send the packets to the user afterwards, and we finally send/indicate those that are marked as OK.

But i have noticed that this is causing the windows 10's task manager to show 0% in every process for their network usage in the processes tab, even tho they are not 0%. And when i turn off the driver it get fixed.

But the weird thing is that his doesn't happen in the performance->ethernet tab and in the resource monitor program, and both of them show the actual network usage.

So what is causing this, and why can the resource monitor and the network tab still see the network usage? I *think* this has to do with the fact that probably resource monitor uses an NDIS filter and the network usage in the processes tab is using a WFP, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your driver call `NdisCopySendNetBufferListInfo` and `NdisCopyRecieveNetBufferListInfo`?

The per-app accounting is indeed tracked using WFP callouts. There is a WFP callout at the top of the network stack that attaches app identity to each NET_BUFFER_LIST. There is another WFP callout at the bottom of the network stack (closest to the hardware) that does the actual byte-counting and bills each app for its network consumption.

If you simply clone the NET_BUFFER_LIST, that doesn't by default copy the app identity that is attached to the NET_BUFFER_LIST. You need to also call one of `NdisCopySendNetBufferListInfo` or `NdisCopyRecieveNetBufferListInfo` to copy that metadata.

Coincidentally there was another NDIS question yesterday for which I am writing the same answer ;) . So rather than write it all out again, you can refer to what I wrote here: [Send doesn't work properly in my NDIS modifying filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69536059/send-doesnt-work-properly-in-my-ndis-modifying-filter-driver)

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, thanks for the answer. No, the way i copy the NET_BUFFERS is by reading its content and then copying it into a member of an internal structure, i then recreate the NET_BUFFER, if the user mode service sends it back to me and doesn't drop it. So do you think this is what's causing the issue? Because in this case I'm just copying the packet content, and can't use NdisCopyRecieveNetBufferListInfo since the destination of copy is not a NET_‌BUFFER. How can i do what that API is doing manually? for example adding some "info" member to my internal structure?

Comment: Note that by content, i meant the packet content. If this is in fact causing this issue, then why can the resource monitor still see the network usage of processes?  Also note that i can't send the entire NET_‌‌BUFFER structures to the user service as its a very large structure, and my own internal structure is much more efficient since i only store the packet content and some little more info about the NET_‌BUFFER.

Comment: And i just realized there is even a bigger problem. Since I'm using  NdisFSendNetBufferListComplete/NdisFIndicateREceiveNetBufferLists, even if i store the original NET_‌َBUFFERS somewhere i can't reuse them when the user sends them back (I'm completing it, because i need to wait for user service's decisions on packets, it sends back those packets that are OK). So what is the solution for me right now?

Comment: NdisCopySendNetBufferListInfo is the only way to preserve the metadata. You'll need to materialize the new NBL sooner, so you have a place to hold that metadata. You can allocate the clone NBL immediately, and use it as an opaque container to hold all metadata, but still show your usermode process your own slimmed down packet descriptor. If the usermode process allows the packet to be sent, then send it with the NBL you previously allocated.