# Copying the NetBufferListInfo array instead of calling NdisCopySendNetBufferListInfo?

Tags: ndis, wfp

I have a kernel driver that seperates every net buffer in every recv/send NBL, and allocates a local structure for every NB which contains the packet content and some other stuff and sends it to a user buffer, and completes/returns the original NBL. The user service then sends back the packets that are OK back to driver and i then finally send/indicate them, by creating an NBL for every packet, and then chaining them together.

This causes the loss of some metadata about the packet, that are seem to be inside NetBufferListInfo (specially WFP metadata).

My question is, can i just save the content of the NetBufferListInfo in the original NBL of the corresponding NB, and save it to my local structure that represents NBs, and the recopy it when i create a NBL that contains that NB?

I thought i should use NdisAllocateCloneNetBufferList + NetBufferListInfo and copy the pointer to the cloned NBL to my local structure as a new member, but the problem with this is that freeing these buffers using NdisFreeCloneNetBufferList will become very complicated, as i create a local structure for every net buffer and insert them in a list that is sent to user service, and each of them could point to a arbitrary NBL (and many of them could be pointing to the same NBL, as i clone the NBL once for multiple NBs inside an NBL), and when the user sends those that are OK to me to, i need to be careful not to free a cloned NBL twice after i indicate/send the NBLs (i assume it will cause double free BSOD). Therefore i need to then keep a reference count for every cloned NBL and make sure to free it when it hits 0, and also some other complications..

So what is the easiest solution for me? Can i just save the content of NetBufferListInfo array of the corresponding NBL in my local structure, and recopy it when i create the final NBL corresponding to a NB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allowed to copy the NetBufferListInfo fields that are fully documented and that you understand semantically. For example, you can copy the `TcpIpChecksumNetBufferListInfo`, because it's fully documented, and semantically it makes sense to propagate it to another NBL that has the same payload.

But there are some fields that are private to the OS, and at least one of those is a *refcounted* pointer. So if you were to copy that field, then return the original NBL, the pointer would dangle. The only way to influence the refcount is to call `NdisCopySendNetBufferListInfo` or `NdisCopyReceiveNetBufferListInfo`, which handle this for you.

TL;DR: You can write code like this:

```
new_nbl->NetBufferListInfo[TcpIpChecksumNetBufferListInfo] = old_nbl->NetBufferListInfo[TcpIpChecksumNetBufferListInfo];
new_nbl->NetBufferListInfo[NetBufferListHashValue] = old_nbl->NetBufferListInfo[NetBufferListHashValue];
. . .
```

but you can't write code like this:

```
RtlCopyMemory(
    new_nbl->NetBufferListInfo,
    old_nbl->NetBufferListInfo,
    sizeof(old_nbl->NetBufferListInfo));
```

since not all the slots are blittable.

Comment: So which part do i need to copy to keep the WFP tracking info for apps, that is used by task manager to show network usage? I tried two things: 1. Allocate a empty NBL and call NdisCopySendNetBufferListInfo with src being the original NBL, 2. Copy the original NBL to a new NBL buffer and then call NdisCopySendNetBufferListInfo. Both causing BSOD. I tried to do this because i can't use NdisAllocateCloneNetBufferList since the overhead is too much in that case, considering that all i need to keep is the required tracking info that is needed by the WFP drivers.

Comment: NdisCopySendNetBufferListInfo is necessary to make taskmgr happy.

Comment: So its only possible if i give NdisCopySendNetBufferListInfo an NBL that was allocated using NdisAllocateCloneNetBufferList, right? No other way around it, for example giving it a fake NBL just to fill out the info in it? Because when i use NdisAllocateCloneNetBufferList the overall network bandwidth reduces by around 50%.

Comment: Nevermind i solved it as follows: I clone a single NBL for multiple NBs, and store its pointer in my internal structure and return/complete the original NBL, then i use the ChildRefCount in the cloned NBL to store the number of references to the NBL (used ChildRefCount just as a place to store my ref count variable, since its already useless), and when I'm finally sending them, i decrement it and only use the cloned NBL for NdisCopyNetBufferListInfo to my newly created NBL, and when the ref count hits zero i free the cloned NBL.